# Problems set-up Single Sign-On using Kerberos authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, kerberos

I need for Ruby on Rail application set authentication via Active Directory using Kerberos authentication.

### Some technical information:

1. I are using Apache
2. installed **mod_auth_kerb**
3. In **httpd.conf** I added **LoadModule auth_kerb_module modules/mod_auth_kerb.so**
4. In **/etc/krb5.conf** I added following configuration

   ```
   [logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log


   [libdefaults]
    default_realm = EU.ORG.COM
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    forwardable = yes

   [realms]
    EU.ORG.COM = {
     kdc = eudc05.eu.org.com:88
     admin_server = eudc05.eu.org.com:749
     default_domain = eu.org.com
    }

   [domain_realm]
    .eu.org.com = EU.ORG.COM
    eu.org.com = EU.ORG.COM

   [appdefaults]
    pam = {
      debug = true
      ticket_lifetime = 36000
      renew_lifetime = 36000
      forwardable = true
      krb4_convert = false
    }
   ```
5. When I test **kinit validuser** and enter password then authentication is successful.
6. **klist returns**:

   ```
   Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_600
   Default principal: validuser@EU.ORG.COM

   Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
   02/08/13 13:46:40  02/08/13 23:46:47  krbtgt/EU.ORG.COM@EU.ORG.COM

           renew until 02/09/13 13:46:40

   Kerberos 4 ticket cache: /tmp/tkt600
   klist: You have no tickets cached
   ```
7. In application Apache configuration I added

   ```
   IfModule mod_auth_kerb.c>
   Location /winlogin>
       AuthType Kerberos
       AuthName "Kerberos Loginsss"
       KrbMethodNegotiate off
       KrbAuthoritative on
       KrbVerifyKDC off
       KrbAuthRealms EU.ORG.COM
       Krb5Keytab /home/crmdata/httpd/apache.keytab
       KrbSaveCredentials off
       Require valid-user
     </Location>
   </IfModule>
   ```
8. I restarted apache

### Now some tests:

1. When I try to access application from Win7, I got pop-up message box, with text:

   ```
   Warning: This server is requesting that your username and password be sent in an insecure manner (basic authentification without a secure connection)
   ```
2. When I enter valid credentials then my application opens successfully, and all works fine.

### Questions:

1. Is ok that for user pop-ups such windows? If I use NTLM authentication then there no such pop-up. 
   I checked IE Internet Options and there 'Enable Integrated Windows Authentication' is checked.
2. Why IE try to send username and password to application apache? If I correct to understand then Windows self must make authentication via Active Directory using Kerberos protocol.
3. When I try to access application from Win7 and I enter **incorrect** credentials to pop-up message box

   - Application say Authentication failed (this is OK)
   - In apache error log I see:

     ```
     [error] [client 192.168.56.1] krb5_get_init_creds_password() failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
     ```
   - But now I cannot get possibility to enter valid credentials, only when I restart IE I can get again pop-up box.

What could be incorrect or missing in my Kerberos setup?

I read in some blog post that probably something is needed to be done in Active Directory side. What exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need `KrbMethodNegotiate on`.
Without that the http client is essentially doing auth-basic to apache and apache is testing the password against the kdc.
Also, for security's sake you should really set `KrbVerifyKDC on`.